# Combine a list of data frames column wise and return a list of combined data frames using R

Tags: r

I would like to combine  two list of data frames element wise and return a list of data frames.  The following code works for the `mtcars` dataset

```
list1=split(mtcars[c(1:16),-11],mtcars[c(1:16),2])
list2=split(data.frame(mtcars[c(1:16),]),mtcars[c(1:16),2])
newList=Map(cbind, list1, list2)
```

How do I modify the `Map` function to just bind a specific column(s) from list2? Thanks

Comment: `newList` but with only say the `carb` column from `list2`

Comment: @hghghghg - like `Map(cbind, list1, lapply(list2, \`[\`, "carb"))` ?

Comment: @thelatemail Perfect! If you write up as an answer I'll accept. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since @thelatemail doesn't want to add an answer here is `purrr` version of his answer.

```
library(purrr)

map2(list1, map(list2, `[`, 'carb'), cbind)
#Or
#map2(list1, map(list2, `[`, 'carb'), dplyr::bind_cols)


#$`4`
#   mpg cyl  disp hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1 22.8   4 108.0 93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
#2 24.4   4 146.7 62 3.69 3.19 20.00  1  0    4    2
#3 22.8   4 140.8 95 3.92 3.15 22.90  1  0    4    2

#$`6`
#   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#3 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#4 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#5 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#6 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4

#$`8`
#   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#2 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#3 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#4 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#5 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#6 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#7 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
```

Comment: the sample data I used is a bad example my actual lists will not have any column names in common

Comment: @hghghghg then I am confused about what you are trying to do and what is your expected output. Could you please include an example which represents your real data and show expected output based on that?

Comment: @ Ronak Shah Thanks for the help I know the sample data was not ideal